# Why do I get this error? Expected expresion before int

Tags: c

I am currently on a problem to find the transpose of a square matrix in C.The algorithm I have used is to create a two dimensional array to store the matrix whose transpose I want to find out. Then I call a function that actually transposes it(since arrays are passed by reference) so that after  the function is called it gets transposed.
The code for the function is as follows:-

```
//transpose of n by n matrix
#include<stdio.h>
void transpose(int arr[int][int]); //prototype declaration line 3
void transpose(int arr[int r][int c]){ //line 4
    int i,j;
    int matB[c][r];
    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        for(j=0;j<r;j++){
            matB[i][j]=arr[j][i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++){
            arr[i][j]=matB[i][j];
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int n,i,j;
    printf("enter the dimensions of square matrix :-");
    int mat[n][n];
    scanf("%d",n);
    printf("please enter the elements of the matrix :-->\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            scanf("%d",&mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    transpose(mat);
    printf("the transpose of the given matrix is:- \n ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d\t",mat[n][n]);
        }
        printf("/n");
    }
}
```

but i get the following errors:-

> line 3:-[Error] expected expression before 'int'
>   line 4 :- [Error] expected expression before 'int'

line 3 and 4 correspond to prototype declaration of the function void() and the function definition as shown in the code

I am currently using DEV C++ as the compiler..
The snap shot of my program :-
[click here to see the snapshot of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZobNg.png)

here' the error i got when compiling:- [click here to see the scanpshot of error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsN2J.png)

Comment: The syntax is fundamentally wrong. You have to study how arrays and functions work. We cannot teach you all that in a SO post, that's too broad a topic.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problem in the above code snippet.

1. Syntax regarding function arguments is wrong. You cannot pass argument type inside square braces.
2. There must be constant column size to be passed with the array in the argument list.

You can do something like this.

```
#define R 10
#define C 100
void transpose(int arr[][C]); // prototype declaration line 2
void transpose(int arr[][C]) { // line 3
    int i, j;
    int matB[C][R];
    for (i = 0; i<C; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<R; j++) {
            matB[i][j] = arr[j][i];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i<R; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<C; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = matB[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to give size of Second Dimensrion of an array ?? ..I .ve created programs where functions take 1D array as paramters but i've never mentioned size of 1D arrays in the functions definitons...why is it mandatory to give size of second dimension in 2D arrays??

Comment: I am not sure, how exactly it works, I am not doing C for some time, but basic principle is about he allocation, you dont have a matrix in physical memory, you can imagine it like a line, so every column and row is allocated like one block. So that is the reason why it is not possible to make col / row variable length. If you want, you have to use dynamic/manual allocation and realloc the space

Answer (score 1):

It will be

```
#define R 10
void transpose(int (*arr)[R]); // prototype declaration line 2
```

or

```
void transpose(int arr[][R]); // prototype declaration line 2
```

`R` is supposed to be a constant. If not for C99

```
void transpose(int r,int c, int (*arr)[r]){ // This will work as prototype
```

and then

```
void transpose(int r,int c, int (*arr)[r]){ 
    ....
}
```

More clearly and easy to use

```
void transpose(int r,int c, int arr[c][r]){
```

In case you don't understand remember that 2d array (array of arrays) converts into pointer to first element - first element is an array so pointer to first element would be `int (*)[]`. From that the earlier solution came.

For example to clarify the previous idea - passing a single dimensional array the same thing also holds. Suppose you have this function,

```
int a[10];
f(a);

...

void f(int a[])
or 
void f(int *a)
```

The thing is here also the decay to the first element happened. Which is nothing but `int*`.